# TileMill Interactive layers not working when added independently with MapBox.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, interactive, mapbox, tilemill

I have a student who is using MapBox.js (v1.6.0) to display some tiles that they made in TileMill. These tiles use the Tooltip functionality provided by TileMill ([documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/tooltips/)) to add some interactivity. My student is also using a MapBox Streets layer to give some detailed views of roadways, etc. The problem is, when I use both of these layers together in the map, the interactivity from the tiles doesn't work.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map("map");

var tilesOSM = L.mapbox.tileLayer("username.id1");
var tilesTileMill = L.mapbox.tileLayer("username.id2");

map
    .addLayer(tilesOSM)
    .addLayer(tilesTileMill)
    .setView(L.latLng(61, -160.5), 4)
    .setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(50,-180), L.latLng(72,-129)));
```

We have tried several iterations of this code, but the only way we can get it to work is by using the L.mapbox.map(3) method and then using the _ insertAtTheBottom_ parameter of the L.map.addLayer() function.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map("map", "username.id2", {});

map
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer("username.id1"), true)
    .setView(L.latLng(61, -160.5), 4)
    .setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(50,-180), L.latLng(72,-129)));
```

My question is three fold.

1. What is the difference between these two implementations?
2. Why is the tileLayer created using L.mapbox.tileLayer() different than the one created and automatically added using L.mapbox.map(3)?
3. Are there plans to address this discontinuity in future changes to the API or will support for interactive tiles be dropped in TileMill 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two implementations?

If you check out [what L.mapbox.map does internally](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/master/src/map.js#L29-L76), it adds a gridLayer and gridControl for the layer you specify. Basically the map constructor makes all of the safe assumptions it could make and does them automatically as a convenience.

> Why is the tileLayer created using L.mapbox.tileLayer() different than the one created and automatically added using L.mapbox.map(3)?

It's the same - there's a gridLayer and gridControl in the mix when you use `L.mapbox.map(3)`, and those are what make things interactive.

> Are there plans to address this discontinuity in future changes to the API

It's not as much a discontinuity than an API design: we decided to keep tileLayers decoupled from gridLayers and gridControls so you can mix & match them - if you want to switch which layer interactive features come from, or disable interactivity without disabling the tile layer, you can.

> will support for interactive tiles be dropped in TileMill 2?

No, you can use TileMill 2 and see how it supports interactivity. We aren't going to remove or phase this out, though vector tiles will have new methods of interaction.

For your second example, you would want something like:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map("map", "username.id2", {});
var gridLayer = L.mapbox.gridLayer("username.id1").addTo(map);
var gridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(gridLayer).addTo(map);

map
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer("username.id1"), true)
    .setView(L.latLng(61, -160.5), 4)
.setMaxBounds(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(50,-180), L.latLng(72,-129)));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and answering. Is the use of GridLayers for this interactivity documented anywhere in the TileMill or MapBox.js reference? I looked everywhere that I thought was reasonable and nothing turned up.

Comment: Yes, documentation for [gridLayers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-mapbox-gridlayer/), [gridControls](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-mapbox-gridcontrol/).